# How to map nested JSON to simple object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, mapping, deserialization

I'd like to map this JSON Data:

```
{"information":{
     "type": "typeA",
     "date": "2018-01-15 12:11:53",
     "user":{
         "name": "John"
         "lastName": "Doe"
     }
}}
```

To this java object:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class InformationModel {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    private String type;
    private String date;
}
```

But it fails and all the values are `null`. I tried adding `@JsonProperty("information.type")` above the `type` variable but without succes.

Is it possible to deserialize the JSON so that it maps to just (this) one class?

EDIT: I am using Spring StreamListener to do the mapping like this:

```
@StreamListener(value = Sink.INPUT)
public void on(InformationModel message) throws IOException {
    // some code using message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I must admit i don't know much about Spring so my answer might well be off the mark, but since you have tagged your question with java, here is my answer (using org.json):

```
String jsonString = "{\"information\":{\"type\": \"typeA\",\"date\": \"2018-01-15 12:11:53\",\"user\":{\"name\": \"John\",\"lastName\": \"Doe\"}}}";

JSONObject o = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONObject obj = o.getJSONObject("information");
String date = obj.getString("date");
//map whatever you want to map here.    
System.out.println(date);
```

Obviously it's pretty basic, but you get the idea. You could probably achieve the same with JSONArray.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

We have several approaches for solving this problem. [As explained here.](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values) .I have tried using Mapping with annotations but it didn't worked for me. What worked is JsonNode as explained below.

[1](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values) **InformationModel.java**

```
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class InformationModel {
private String type;
private String date;
private String lastName;
private String name;
//getters and setters
}
`
```

[2] **TestDemo.java**

```
    public class TestDemo { 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonParseException,
            JsonMappingException, IOException { 
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode j = mapper.readTree(new File("information.json"));
        InformationModel m = new InformationModel();
        m.setType(j.get("information").get("type").textValue());
        m.setDate(j.get("information").get("date").textValue());
        m.setName(j.get("information").get("user").get("name").textValue());
        m.setLastName(j.get("information").get("user").get("lastName").textValue());        
        mapper.writeValue(new File("outputfile.json"), j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) . there is a good tutorial [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-customizing-de-serialization-and-adding-instance-creators-via-jsonadapter) 
you can take advantage of custom serialization.

**if you want to use your current POJO structure follow this :** 
code to deserialize json

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

JsonDeserializer<UserDate> deserializer = InformationModelDeserializer() ; 
// implementation detail  
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(InformationModel .class, deserializer);

Gson customGson = gsonBuilder.create();  
InformationModel customObject = customGson.fromJson(yourJson, InformationModel .class);
```

code for the InformationModelDeserializer.java

```
public class InformationModelDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<InformationModel > {  
@Override
public InformationModel deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    //intercept the json to convert it to your desired shape
    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject userJsonObject json.getAsJsonObject("user")


    return new InformationModel (
        userJsonObject.get("name").getAsString(),
        userJsonObject.get("lastname").getAsString(),
        jsonObject.get("type").getAsString(),
        jsonObject.get("date").getAsString(),

    );
}
}
```

finally put this @anotaion before your InformationModel class `@JsonAdapter(InformationModelDeserialize.class)`

---

**or easily change your POJO to**

```
Information.java

public class Information {
    private String type;
    private String date;

    private User user;

    //.....
}
```

User.java

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

  // .....
 }
```

and easily deesrealize :

```
Information info=new Gson().fromJson(yourJson,Information.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the only solution is to have the same class structure as the JSON (left out the imports and packages for readability):

**InformationModel.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class InformationModel {
    private Information information;

    //Getter and Setter
}
```

**Information.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Information {
    private String type;
    private String date;

    private User user;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**User.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```